# SSMS Project but do not move files

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Whenever I create a SSMS project/solution and add existing files to the project, there doesn't seem to be an option to keep location of existing files, it always wants to copy the file into the project folder.

This means multiple projects with same file cannot share that file and is contrary to how visual studio works.

Is there a way around this?

I tried updating the project file but if you put in a different path it just gives an error as it's looking in c:\windows.... for the file.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click your Project in solution Explorer, Add, Existing Item, , Add As Link. You will now have an absolute path for that file. I haven't found a way to get relative paths, though. But I do use absolute paths all the time, to share same files between projects.

Comment: Thanks, well that wasn't obvious. I thought they'd remove the dropdown buttons from dialog boxes ages ago. I was looking for an add as link checkbox like you get in all other systems :)

Comment: Yeah, the drop-down checkbox feels indeed a bit ... old-school. :-)